# LLC resonant capacitor RMS voltage and output capacitor ESR calculation

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, resonant-converter, llc-converter

I have a question about the [TI LLC document.](https://www.ti.com/seclit/ml/slup263/slup263.pdf)

On page 25, *Select the Resonant Capacitor,* I don't understand why it can use this formula to calculate the RMS value. Could someone tell me how to get this formula?

[image]

On Page 27, I don't understand why it can use (pi/4)*Io*2 to get Irect_peak. how to get this value?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rms value of a periodic voltage waveform affected by a dc (average) value and an ac ripple (rms) is determined by: \$V_{rms}=\sqrt{V_{ac}^2+V_{dc}^2}\$. You thus measure or determine the ac rms ripple value straddling around the dc offset and then apply the formula.

For the LLC, the author knows that the rms ac current in the cap. is 2.6 A. Multiply by the cap. impedance at the operating frequency (resonance) and you have the rms ac voltage ripple across the cap. At steady state, the dc voltage is \$\frac{V_{in}}{2}\$. Apply the definition of the rms voltage and you have your equation of \$V_{Cr,rms}\$:

[image]

For the current, at resonance, the dc current leaving the two diodes which splits between the cap. (ac) and the load (dc) is equal to \$I_o=\frac{2I_p}{\pi}\$. You derive this value easily or you can find ready-made formulas for full-wave rectification.  From this value, you can extract the peak value. Then, considering a net zero dc current in the capacitor at steady-state, the ac current ripple in the cap is the total ac current minus the output current:

[image]

To test these values, I have run a simple example with the SIMPLIS demo. This is an open-loop LLC circuit part of the 60+ SIMPLIS [templates](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf) you can download from my webpage and the circuit delivers 10 A from a 380-V dc source:

[image]

If you run the simulation, you can verify the calculated values with the formulas supplied in the application note:

[image]